# Is there anything like Javascript Eval in C# or Java

Tags: c#, java, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using eval in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/using-eval-in-java)

In javascript i can call a function using eval like :

```
eval('my_javascript_code;')
```

Is there anything like that in C# or JAVA which lets me run C# or JAVA code?

```
String time = Eval("My csharp code");
```

Or Am I completely off the track?

Comment: You can use [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) in Java. This produces a scripting library for Java and is used in many debuggers for ad hoc expressions. However, use of "eval" or dynamic code is discouraged in Java (and I suspect most languages it's not a good idea)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct analogue - there is no built in function that will take a string and run it as executable code.

You can use the different [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) options of either platform to [execute code dynamically](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=dynamic%20code%20execution&aq=f&oq=dynamic%20code%20execution&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.6012&sugexp=chrome,mod=11&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). These include creating classes in code, compiling them and executing them and is not easy or fast.

Comment: Not easy or fast indeed.  Last I tried this in C#, it took over 100 milliseconds to execute a trivial arithmetic operation in this fashion.

Comment: @Downvoter - care to comment?

Comment: Not my downvote, but I guess the answer was a bit vague.  Maybe add some links, or searchable terms like "runtime compiling" and "dynamic assembly loading"?