# How to convert string to actual code

Tags: c#

C# code I want to execute :

```
FullReservationDataControl1.SetData(Reservation);
```

but instead of typing 'FullReservationDataControl1' I want to loop it, so I made a for loop to get me an array of strings having this content : `FullReservationDataControl+x`where x is a number. so my question is how to use a string to execute a command and not ending with an error due to execution of :

```
"FullReservationDataControl4".SetData(Reservation);
```

Comment: You want an array of controls.

Comment: I think you will need to structure your classes and code for a better approach to handle this issue, but here is a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720565/is-there-anything-like-javascript-eval-in-c-sharp-or-java and this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11939/Evaluate-C-Code-Eval-Function   http://www.ckode.dk/programming/eval-in-c-yes-its-possible/

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there's nothing like eval() built into C#.

For your purposes, though, given the code you've posted above, this would be better done by creating an IEnumerable of objects. Instead of saying:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{ 
    // does not work as written
    ("FullReservationDataControl" + i.ToString()).SetData(Reservation)
}
```

create and keep reference to a collection of your controls like so:

```
List<FullReservationDataControl> fullResDataControls = new List<FullReservationDataControl>() 
    { 
        /* add all your FullReservationDataControls here */ 
    };
```

then loop through it:

```
foreach (FullReservationDataControl resControl in fullResDataControls)
{
    resControl.SetData(Reservation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Reflection and invoke the SetData method on an object identified by a name (string).

References:
[Reflection: How to Invoke Method with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202381/reflection-how-to-invoke-method-with-parameters)

I particularly like this approach:

[How do I use reflection to invoke a private method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135443/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-invoke-a-private-method)

```
static class AccessExtensions
{
    public static object Call(this object o, string methodName, params object[] args)
    {
        var mi = o.GetType ().GetMethod (methodName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance );
        if (mi != null) {
            return mi.Invoke (o, args);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Sample use in your case:

```
(someResultOfSearchByName as someExpectedType).Call("SetData", Reservation);
```

Sorry for the "some", but you gave no hint if this is a WinForms or WPF app.